# How to make some columns align left and some column align center in React Table - React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-table

Hello Stack overflow members

This is array for the column headers. I want column 1 to column 5 left align (all the header, sub header and table data cells of column 1 to column 5 to be left aligned) while I I want column 6 to column 8 to be centre aligned (all the header, sub header and table data cells of column 1 to column 5 to be centre aligned). Please help me to solve this as I can only make either all columns center or all columns left aligned.

**I want to implement this particular style on column 6 to 8 header as shown in this image.** [image].

**If you can help me, please provide a demo on CodeSandbox**

This is my Header Data

```
const columns = [
 {
    Header: 'Column 1',
        columns: [
           {
               Header: 'S Column 1',
               accessor: 'firstName'
           }
      ]
  },
  {
      Header: 'Column 2',
       columns: [
         {
            Header: 'S Column 2',
            accessor: 'firstName'
          }
       ]
     },
    {
            Header: 'Column 3',
            columns: [
    {
            Header: 'S Column 3',
            accessor: 'firstName'
          }
         ]
   },
    {
          Header: 'Column 4',
          columns: [
    {
            Header: 'S column 4',
            accessor: 'firstName'
     }
    ]
      },
     {
     Header: 'Column 5',
    columns: [
    {
    Header: 'S column 5',
     accessor: 'firstName'
    }
   ]
   },
  {
     Header: 'Column 6',
     columns: [
  {
        Header: 'S column 6a',
        accessor: 'firstName'
  },
   {
        Header: 'S column 6b',
        accessor: 'firstName'
    },
    {
        Header: 'S column 6c',
        accessor: 'firstName'
     },
    {
         Header: 'S column 6d',
         accessor: 'firstName'
    }
  ]
     },
      {
     Header: 'Column 7',
     columns: [
     {
      Header: 'S column 7',
         accessor: 'firstName'
   }
    ]
     },
      {
        Header: 'Column 8',
        columns: [
      {
       Header: 'S Column 8a',
       accessor: 'firstName'
      },
     {
       Header: 'S Column 8b',
       accessor: 'firstName'
     },
    {
    Header: 'S Column 8c',
    accessor: 'firstName'
    },
    {
      Header: 'S Column 8d',
      accessor: 'firstName'
      }
     ]
      },
      ];
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Something like this should do the job

```
columns: [
           {                 
              accessor: "firstName",
              Header: () => (
                    <div
                      style={{
                        textAlign:"right"
                      }}
                    >S Column 1</div>)
           },
```

> If you can help me, please provide a demo on CodeSandbox

Play [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/64ky3q4zqk)

[image]

**Update after OP comment**

> but for columns which will be centre aligned , their sub cell data
> will also be centre aligned

Manipulate cell styles like this

```
Cell: row => <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{row.value}</div>
```

Play it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/64ky3q4zqk)

[image]

**Method 2:**

Use can use the `headerClassName` and specify a class name, in that class you can specify the rule `text-align:center`

So the code will look  like

```
const columns = [{
  Header: 'Column 5',
  accessor: 'name',
  headerClassName: 'your-class-name'
},
{
......
}
]
```

**Method 3:**

If you have lot of headers, adding headerClassName in all headers is a pain. In that case you can set the class name in `ReactTableDefaults`

```
import ReactTable, {ReactTableDefaults} from 'react-table';

const columnDefaults = {...ReactTableDefaults.column, headerClassName: 'text-left-classname'}
```

and in the ReactTable, use like this

```
<ReactTable
 ...
 ...
 column = { columnDefaults }
 />
```

> Note: if you are using bootstrap you can assign the inbuilt class `text-center` to `headerClassName`

Comment: Hello thanks man, but for columns which will be centre aligned , their sub cell data will also be centre aligned

Comment: Can you help me in this regard by slightly modifying your answer so that the sub cells also follow the header pattern, center aligned header will have centre aligned Data , while left aligned header will have left aligned data

Comment: how can i align the cell center that has formateDate. such as {
      Header: 'Submitted Date',
      accessor: 'createdAt',
      Cell: (e) => formatDate(e.value),
    },

Comment: @Tenz  try this `Cell: (e) => <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{formatDate(e.value)}</div>` or any other approach mentioned above

Comment: you may also need to add `width: "100%"`

Answer (score 1):

There's a few options. One is that the column configuration takes a `style` property, which you can use to pass in custom CSS including `textAlign` (see [here](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme) for docs on column properties). Into each column pass the desired `textAlign` style value.

Another option would be to pass a custom `Cell` property to the columns, and wrap your content in an element to which you've assigned the text alignment styling. Something like:

```
{
    Header: "Name",
    accessor: "name",
    Cell: cellContent => <RightAlign>{cellContent}</RightAlign>
},
```

(Google around to see the docs and example usages)

Comment: Kiranvj almost solved my problem is for columns which will be centre aligned , their sub cell data will also be centre aligned. Can you help me in this regard by slightly modifying the answer of kiranvj so that the sub cells also follow the header pattern, center aligned header will have centre aligned Data , while left aligned header will have left aligned data.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `headerStyle: {textAlign: 'right'}` to the column will do the trick without the need for a custom renderer for the header cell. A little cleaner imho

```
{
    Header: "Name",
    accessor: "name",
    headerStyle: {textAlign: 'right'}
},
```

###### UPDATE:

This is an option in v6, but it does not appear to have made it to v7.

Comment: Sorry for the delay @Nick. This was a feature in v6 https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6#columns, but i don't think it was kept in v7.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it this way in my project. As per your code, you can implement it as follows,

```
columns: [
           {             
              accessor: "firstName",
              Header: "S Column 1",
              style: {
                textAlign: 'right'
              }
           }
]
```

You can adjust it as per your other columns.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm this does not seem to affect anything?

Answer (score -2):

## Using CSS + headerClassName

**CSS**

```
.ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-tr-align-left {
    text-align: left;
}

.ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-tr-align-right{
    text-align: right;
}
```

**Column Config**

```
const columns = [
 {
    Header: 'Column 1',
    columns: [
           {
               Header: 'S Column 1',
               accessor: 'firstName',
               // Apply custom className to header
               headerClassName: 'rt-tr-align-left'
           }
      ]
  },
  {
     Header: 'Column 2',
     columns: [{
            Header: 'S Column 2',
            accessor: 'firstName',
            // Apply custom className to header
            headerClassName: 'rt-tr-align-right'

          }
       ]
       /// etc
     }]
```